# Django Modelform: cannot import name

Tags: django, django-forms

```
#### model using ModelForm: models.py
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    custAdd = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
            db_table = 'tb_amit_test'
            ordering = ['-name']
            verbose_name_plural = 'customers'

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return ('customers_customers', (), { 'customers_name': self.name })

class customerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model=customers


#### View:views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from mtcc_customer_db import customers
from mtcc_customer_db import customerForm
from django.template import RequestContext


def adddata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            f=custform(request.POST)
            if f.is_valid():
                    newcust=f.save(commit=False)
                    newcust.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render_to_response('index.html',
context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#### URLs:
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mtcc_customer_db import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)

urlpatterns +=patterns('mtcc_customer_db.customers.views',
(r'^customers/$', 'adddata'),)

### Template: customer.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block site_wrapper %}
    <div id="main">
    {% include "tags/navigation.html" %}

    <a href="#content" class="skip_link">Skip to main content</a>
    <form action="." method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{name}}">
     <input type="text" name="custAdd" id="custAdd" value="{{custAdd}}">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>.........
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the error in the browser:

Request Method:         GET
Request URL:    someaddress.customers/
Django Version:         1.4.3
Exception Type:         ImportError
Exception Value:

--->>cannot import name customerForm

Where am i going wrong?? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from your_module_name.models import customerForm
```

in your views.py file

Comment: What is your app module name?

Comment: I have a mtcc_customer_db project and have a customer app in it. therefore the app is called customers, i have also tried from customers import customerForm and from customers.models import customerForm... gives same results does not find either..

Comment: So your project folder structure is something like:
    mtcc_customer_db
    --customers
    ----models.py

Comment: to be exact... the complete path: /srv/www/mtcc_customer_db/mtcc_customer_db/customers-- models.py, views.py

Comment: did you try: from mtcc_customer_db.customers.models import customerForm

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked!! came in the morning.. used "from mtcc_customer_db.customers.models import customerForm" and all is well. Highly appreciate your help... CHEERS!!

Comment: @user2028630 in the future make sure you restart your apache instance after changing your python code to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

The form is in models.py (*), so you should be doing `from mtcc_customer_db.models import customerForm`.

(*) note that it should probably be in forms.py anyway, but still.